# STL list<mystruct> return problem

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

I am trying to use STL list in a project but i have the following problem.

I want my list to store a struct. For example this one

```
struct mystruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Then i am using an iterator to access every struct in the list like this.

```
list<mystruct> L;
list<mystruct>::iterator lit;
for(lit=L.begin();lit!=L.end();lit++) 
    {
        if(lit->x==1) cout << "<NUM," << lit->x << "> ";
        if(lit->y==2) cout << "<ID," << lit->y << "> ";
    }
```

This works but i want to get one struct at a time so i made this func

```
mystruct Myclass::next(void)
{
    if(lit!=L.end()) 
    {
        lit++;
    }
    return *lit;
}
```

but i get an error after running it and i cannot understand why this happens.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Whats the error and what is the interface of Myclass? (Is lit a member for example)

Comment: Just a suggestion, when using iterators (like you do, in a for loop, etc..) use the prefix incremental (++lit rather than lit++), its more efficient.

Comment: The error is "list iterator not incrementable".

Answer (score 3):

```
mystruct Myclass::next(void)
{
    if(lit!=L.end()) 
    {
        lit++;
    }
    return *lit;
}
```

You increment unless you already are at the end, but the dereferencing happens every time, regardless of if you are at the end or not. To help around that problem, consider returning a pointer, and then a `0` pointer if you are at the end.

```
mystruct* Myclass::next(void)
{
    if(lit!=L.end() && ++lit != L.end()) 
    {
        // dereference to get the struct, and then return the address of the struct
        return &*lit;
    }
    return 0;
    // or nullptr in C++0x
}
```

And then check agains `0` (or `nullptr`) in the code where you use `Myclass::next`.

Comment: -1. Wrong solution. If inside the `if` block, what if `lit++` makes `lit` to reach the end? Undefined behavior. You need to check **after** `lit++`.

Comment: @Nawaz: D'oh, my mistake. That was me thinking a bit fast, corrected. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing `next()`  that returns an object (rather than pointer), then I think you also need to write `has_next()` function which you should call to inspect if there is item in the list or not, before calling `next()`. Something like this:

```
bool has_next()
{
   list<mystruct>::iterator temp = lit;
   return ++temp != L.end();
}

mystruct Myclass::next(void)
{
    if( !has_next()) 
    {
         throw "end of the list is reached";
    }
    ++lit;
    return *lit;
}

//usage
while(myClassInstance.has_next())
{
      mystruct s = myClassInstance.next();
      //work with s
}
```

---

Or if you decide to return pointer to `mystruct` from `next()`, then `has_next()` is not so needed.  You can write this:

```
mystruct *  Myclass::next(void)
{
    ++lit;
    if( lit == L.end() ) 
         return NULL;
    return &(*lit);
}
```

Comment: One question though, does `++lit` still evaluate to `L.end()` if it was the end before?

Comment: @Xeo: No. That would be undefined behavior. But I suppose that is caller's responsibility to make sure that it does NOT call `next()` once it returns `NULL`, just like you don't `++it` when `it` reaches `end()`.

Comment: @Nawaz "list iterator not incrementable"

Comment: @fokpop: its impossible to help you if you don't post all the relevant code, along with the "exact" error that compiler prints.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
mystruct Myclass::next(void)
{
    if(lit!=L.end()) 
    {
        lit++;
    }
    return *lit;
}
```

First how is lit defined?
Second, if lit is equal to L.end() you should return some default value, not dereference it, because if you do, you are causing an undefined behaviour. If you are lucky, your program will crash.